# Looking for jenkins plugin for custom (and multiple) queues

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to find jenkins plugin for the following use case:

- Several freestyle projects (project A, B, and C) are created on Jenkins, each triggered by SVN commit.
- Each project has a separate queue, Qa, Qb and Qc. Each queue will record a bunch of build job request.
- Suppose SVN pre-commit hook detects a commit attempt for project A. It then query project A's status on Jenkins to see if it's running.

  > - If it is in the middle of a run, the hook will reject the commit request and record the user's username and commit log message to the end of queue Qa, and send an email notifying the user its commit is rejected and queued.
  > - If project A is not in the middle of a run, the hook will check the jobs queued in Qa. If Qa is empty, the commit will go through the hook and a job of project A will run. If Qa is not empty, the hook will check whether the committer is the same user as the job at the head of the queue. If they are the same user, the commit will go through and run. Otherwise the commit is rejected and the user is notified.
- When the current build job of project A finishes an email is sent to notify all the users, and the next job in queue is ready to run. Jenkins will wait for a commit to trigger it.
- Queue should be able to be manipulated via Jenkins web GUI. Job deleting and order adjustment should be supported.

Is there a similar plugin that I can modify or should I write a new plugin for this?

Thanks a lot,
Peng

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, this sounds like a pretty inefficient process...but, you can probably accomplish most of it with jenkins if you really want to, but it will require some custom programming. I don't know that I understand the multiple queues you're describing. Jenkins has one build queue, but for each job you will be able to see the "queue" of builds that have occurred so far.

You can setup up job to not allow concurrent runs which will accomplish only having one of that specific job running at any given time.

As far as rejecting a commit when a job is already building, you can write code to do that, but why? More difficult is to then queue the job to run after you've rejected the commit. You would have to store off the commit changes somewhere and then somehow try to recommit which would then fire off your job. Not an easy task. Why not let the commit go through and then let the next jobs queue up to run with each commit. Your process sounds like it would cripple your developers, especially if builds took a long time, and you are quite frankly working against the spirit of continuous integration that jenkins is designed for.

The things you described in your last 2 bullet points (emailing, deleting, job ordering) should already be build in features of jenkins (depending on what you mean by "job ordering").

Comment: Hi, Ellis, thanks for the reply. Yeah the approach is clumsy and somehow against the CI spirit. Here are our reasons:
1) Our code is a signal processing simulation platform.
2) For each commit, we have a bunch of sanity check test cases to run by the CI job, and the simulation results for these test cases are checked against the results of previous commit, and are also required to be committed to SVN. If revision N+1's sanity check is kicked off while revision N's is running, N+1's "previous" result will not be N's, but will be N-1's instead, because N's result is not done yet.

Comment: We don't want the simulation result change to reflect multiple commits, because if the result fails our checking criteria, we'll immediately know who cause the failure and let him/her either give an explanation on the change in case the result change is reasonable, or debug the code to fix it in case the result change is a buggy failure. I think that's what prevents us from a more straightforward CI model. Anyway, welcome to prove me wrong and drop better suggestions!

Comment: With Jenkins, you can fire off one build per commit. That should allow simultaneous commits and more granular detection of who broke the build. Granted, if 2 commits are made close together and the first commit breaks the build, it will break both build 1 and build 2, which doesn't really tell you immediately whether there was problem with commit #2 without digging into the results. You will know for sure, though, that there was a problem with commit #1.

Comment: Yeah that's true. However suppose the first commit did not break the build, and it slightly alters the simulation result (which would still be accepted by the sanity check criteria). If commit 2 is close to commit 1, commit 2's simulation result will have the same "previous" result as commit 1. If commit 2 comes after 1 is done, commit 2's "previous" result will be commit 1's result. Since the sanity check criteria is based on delta change between 2 consecutive commits, the 2nd commit (and it's build & sanity check tests) can only be started after simulation result of commit 1 is obtained.

Comment: I think this sanity check criteria thing is the main reason that prevent us from straightforward commit and quicker iteration, but changing the criteria would be tough and in some cases impractical.

Answer (score 0):

```
I have similar needs 
I define jobs jobA，jobB，jobC as upstream job,
each  upstream job will trigger different number download stream jobs, with different params,the number according to my config file.

we config a lot of download stream jobs，we can call them download stream jobs pool, like thead pool.
maybe dsjobs1，dsjobs2，dsjobs3，dsjobs4 ..... until to dsjobs50. each dsjobs bind to one build server，and each dsjob concurrency is not allowed.

when trigger jobsA, it will dispatch some subtasks to download stream jobs, like :
jobA -> dsjobs1 with param1
     -> dsjobs2 with param2
     -> dsjobs3 with param3

so did jobB and jobC.

so I want a  customs queue, I trigger subtasks to the queue, the queue dispatch subtasks to the download stream jobs pool.
each download stream job only running one task at the same times.
if all download stream jobs are running, the subtasks should be wait in the queue.
if there is one idle download stream jobsm, the queue will do dispatch.
```